# Double Commander: How to change spacing between lines?

Tags: double-commander

I am using Double Commander on Windows 10 and it works very well but I find the spacing between lines in the folder panes to be too high, is it possible to reduce the number of pixels between lines? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Double Commander post
[space between lines](https://doublecmd.h1n.ru/viewtopic.php?t=4314)
says to go to menu
Options > Icons > Icon size > File panel.

Reducing the Icon size also reduces the space between lines.

Other advice was to reduce `<ExtraLineSpan>` in `config.xml`.
This element is decribed in
[Settings in doublecmd.xml](https://doublecmd.github.io/doc/en/configxml.html) as:

> This setting allows to add some extra pixels to the height allowed for
> each element displayed in the file panels. The value is interpreted
> directly in pixels.
> Default value is 2.
> *Example*:
> `<ExtraLineSpan>2</ExtraLineSpan>`